# Calculating a complex integral via Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate following integral $$
\int_{1- i\infty}^{1+i\infty}\frac{a^z}{z^2} dz
$$  where $0<a<\infty$. I considered the following curve [image]

I need to show that $$
\int_{C_R}^{}\frac{a^z}{z^2} dz
$$ goes to zero as $R$ goes to zero ($C_R$ is only the half circle exluding the line segment). So by Residue theorem I can calculate the answer. However I am stuck there. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If $1 \leq a <\infty$, then $$
\left| {\int_{C_R } {\frac{{a^z }}{{z^2 }}dz} } \right| \le \int_{C_R } {\frac{{a^{\Re z} }}{{\left| z \right|^2 }}\left| {dz} \right|}  \le \int_{C_R } {\frac{a}{{\left| z \right|^2 }}\left| {dz} \right|}  \le \frac{a}{{(R - 1)^2 }}\int_{C_R } {\left| {dz} \right|}  = \frac{a}{{(R - 1)^2 }}\pi R.
$$

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much but my only question is it might be silly but I could not see why $ |a^z| \leq |a^{\Re(z)}|$. I know this makes sense for $e^z$ but I could not see here.

Comment: $$
\left| {a^z } \right| = \left| {e^{z\log a} } \right| = e^{\Re (z\log a)}  = e^{\log a\Re z}  = a^{\Re z} 
$$ since $\log a$ is real.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!